# creating table header with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having two issues with my table, One of them is that I want it to only show when I click a button but when i do it shows and then hides and the other is how do I send a parameter based on the select option to this createtable function 
This is part of my code

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
<select multiple class="form-control" style = "width:250px"id = "theselect">
        <option selected disabled> Chose a number </option>
        <option> all </option>
        <option> 1 </option>
        <option> 2 </option>
    </select> 


    <button type="submit" id = "load" class="btn btn-default">Load</button>
</form>

<div id ="test">



</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example").hide();
    $("#load").click(function(e){

        $("#example").show();

    });
});

function createTable(param){
   var contents = "<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%' border>";
    ....
   ....
    $('#test').append(contents); append it to div 
}
$(document).ready(createTable(1));


</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this example. It gets the selected values, and inserts them into a table, and table into the dom... HTH.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#load").click(function(e){
        var bits = $('#theselect').val();
        $("#example").hide();
        $('#test').html('');
        createTable(bits)
        $("#example").show();
    });
});

function createTable(param){
   var contents = "<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%' border><tbody><tr><td>"+param+"</td></tr></tbody></table>";

    $('#test').append(contents)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple class="form-control" style = "width:250px"id = "theselect">
    <option selected disabled> Chose a number </option>
    <option> all </option>
    <option> 1 </option>
    <option> 2 </option>
</select>

<button id = "load" class="btn btn-default">Load</button>

<div id ="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the table is getting hidden again is because you've set `type="submit"` on your button. This means that after the click event handler is done processing, it will submit the form, which causes the page to reload. When it reloads, the table is hidden again. If you change it to `type="button"` that will prevent that.

You can get the currently selected value of the select, using jquery, with this:

```
$('#theselect').val();
```

You can then pass this in to your createTable function (or just get the value using that code, from within the function itself).

Also, it's a really bad idea to create markup from within your JavaScript. It's going to make future maintenance a nightmare, and if it gets complex enough, it could start causing performance issues. It's much better to keep your markup separate, and then show/hide it as needed via JS.

Comment: Good one, I didn't notice the `type="submit"` on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#load").click(function(e){
        createTable($("#theselect").val());
        $("#example").show(); // In case of class 'display' gives it 'display:none'
    });
});

function createTable(param){
   var contents = "<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%' border>";

    $('#test').append(contents);
}
```

`#example` doesn't exists at the beginning so I removed `$("#example").hide()`.

Comment: for some reason it is still hiding after the page loads

Comment: @user3547086 what is still hidding ? The table isn't suposed to be shown only when user clicks the button load?